# Trouble to display Table Data with Corona SDK with Widget using display.newRetinaText

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am following the videos for J.A. Whyte in his tutorial, a fantastic Corona SDK business app tutorial in my opinion.   I typed in the code as he typed it in the screen.  I've added some trouble shooting code but while I get the grid to display, I can not get the data to populate the screen.  I've also created a build for my phone, and run it on a previous sdk build 2013.12.7.  Here is the code.  You can comment out the reference to the ping.

```
local widget = require("widget")

local top = display.statusBarHeight
local listRecs ={}
local list = nil

local nameData = {"Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Jones", "Brown", "Davis", "Miller", "Wilson", "Moore", "Taylor", "Anderson", "Thomas", "Jackson", "White", "Harris"}


local function setup()
    local bg = display.newRect(0,top, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight - top)
    bg:setFillColor(0,155,73)
    list = widget.newTableView {top = top +10, height = 450 }
    maskFile = "mask.png"

end

local function loadData()
    for x =1 , #nameData do
        listRecs[x] = {}
        listRecs[x].name = nameData[x]
        listRecs[x].age = math.random(18,35)
        listRecs[x].showDel = false
        print(listRecs[x].name.." "..listRecs[x].age)
    end
end

local function showRecords()

    local function onRowRender(event)
        local row = event.row
        local rowGroup = event.view
        local idx = row.index or 0
        local color = 0

        print("the index value is: "..idx)


        row.textObj = display.newRetinaText(listRecs[idx].name, 0, 0, "Helvetica", 16)
        row.textObj:setTextColor( color )
        row.textObj:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)
        row.textObj.x = 20
        row.textObj.y = rowGroup.contentHeight*0.35

        row.textObj2 = display.newRetinaText(listRecs[idx].age, 0, 0, "Helvetica", 16)
        row.textObj2:setTextColor( color )
        row.textObj2:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)
        row.textObj2.x = 20
        row.textObj2.y = rowGroup.contentHeight*0.65    

        rowGroup:insert(row.textObj)
        rowGroup:insert(row.textObj2)   

    end -- onRowRender

    local function rowListener(event)

    end -- row Listener

    for x = 1, #listRecs do
            list:insertRow{
            onRender = onRowRender,
            listner = rowListener
        }
    end

end -- showRecords

setup()

loadData()

showRecords()
```

Answer (score 0):

Those code are too old for current build.
Try this with current build please, hope it helps:

```
local widget = require("widget")

local top = display.statusBarHeight
local listRecs ={}
local list = nil

local nameData = {"Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Jones", "Brown", "Davis", "Miller", "Wilson", "Moore", "Taylor", "Anderson", "Thomas", "Jackson", "White", "Harris"}


local function setup()
    local bg = display.newRect(0,top, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight - top)
    bg:setFillColor(0,155,73)
    list = widget.newTableView {top = top +10, height = 450 ,onRowRender = onRowRender,     onRowTouch = onRowTouch,}
    maskFile = "mask.png"

end

local function loadData()
    for x =1 , #nameData do
        listRecs[x] = {}
        listRecs[x].name = nameData[x]
        listRecs[x].age = math.random(18,35)
        listRecs[x].showDel = false
        print(listRecs[x].name.." "..listRecs[x].age)
    end
end
function onRowRender(event)
    local row = event.row
    local groupContentHeight = row.contentHeight
    local idx = row.index or 0

    print("the index value is: "..idx)

    local textObj = display.newText( row, listRecs[idx].name, 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 16 )
    textObj.x = 20
    textObj.anchorX = 0
    textObj.y = groupContentHeight * 0.35
    textObj:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0 )  
    local textObj2 = display.newText( row, listRecs[idx].age, 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 16 )
    textObj2.x = 20
    textObj2.anchorX = 0
    textObj2.y = groupContentHeight * 0.65
    textObj2:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0 )  
end 
-- onRowRender
local function showRecords()




local function rowListener(event)

end -- row Listener

for x = 1, #listRecs do

        list:insertRow{
    }
end

end -- showRecords

setup()

loadData()

showRecords()
```